# Have people ever been deterred from reporting an event because the report might seem impossible?

Tags: crime, crowd-psychology

I'm seeking occurrences in history where people or organizations did some activity, but witnesses who would speak about the activity, would be considered insane, because of the unlikely nature of the event. Because of this 'deterrent effect', the activity could be continued.

It can be crimes or another event that fits the description. The term 'activity' can be interpreted freely.
It can also be a 'cover up' from the organization, in the sense that people 'act as if'. People can be dressed or act in a way that deters them to report an accompanying event. In that way, the accompanying activity isn't reported because of the 'cover up'.

Comment: Thanks for the revision!

Comment: Happens every day ...

Comment: I thought I saw an H:SE question accepted without revision and answered; I didn't bother to check, because nobody would believe me even if it happened.

Comment: Presumably, in order to know this happened, someone would need to be deterred from reporting the event but not deterred from reporting their failure to report the event.

Comment: Oops, this was closed before I decided to post my answer (not that I object to this being closed, this is why I was on the fence). But you may want to check [Millikan's oil drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment), where apparently some researchers "tuned" their experiments in order to get results closer to the original (but flawed) experiment.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this is commonplace in minority communities.  Can someone who studies rape and racial violence comment?

Answer (score 2):

What if I told you that a US court held that a police officer cannot be held responsible for stealing from a suspect during a search?

Let me rephrase: Alice claims that Officer Bob stole $100k from her during a search. Bob answers: I cannot be held responsible for stealing from a suspect (he makes no comments about the veracity of Alice's claim). A US Court agrees.

Would you believer me? Would you think I am crazy? Or maybe repeating some sort of anti-American propaganda?

Please take a look at

- [Qualified immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_immunity)

  - [Will The Supreme Court Finally Do Something About Qualified Immunity?](https://ij.org/sc_podcast/134/)
- [Jessop v. City of Fresno: Police officers entitled to qualified immunity for alleged theft of property while executing search warrant](https://www.law.com/therecorder/almID/1567633316CA1716756/?slreturn=20200419144746)

  - [IJ Amicus](https://www.supremecourt.gov/DocketPDF/19/19-1021/138419/20200317143611916_39525%20pdf%20Gammon.pdf)

Comment: +1 lol, when i said "Happens every day" i actualy thought of such and similar cases ...